# Webstorm 6.0 Cannot Type in Words, but Can Copy/Paste

Tags: windows-7, webstorm

If I Copy/Paste anything in the WebStorm, the Chrome can show the changes. That should mean the Live Edit can work, but I cannot type any single letter there. I totally got lost.

[update]

I have just updated the title. Sorry for the confustion. It is not the live edit problem, even not in the normal edit mode, I cannot type any words. I guess it may be the problem of the webstorm on windows 7. I have just tried to install it on XP. It works well. I will try Mac as well and update later.

[update]

Above issues were happened to webstorm 6.0.2a on windows 7.
I have just webstorm 6.0.2a on Mac. There was no problem. I unintalled webstorm 6.0.2a on Windows 7. Instead, I downloaded and installed webstorm 5.0.4. There is no problems as well, so it looks this is a standalone issue for webstorm 6.0.2a on windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have angular.js plugin installed? If yes, please check if there is kotlin-runtime.jar in your ~.WebStorm6\config\plugins\angularjs-plugin\lib; if it's missing, please make sure to remove the angularjs plugin and reinstall it from the repository

Comment: Yes, this caused the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I know that this topic is old but it helped me with Webstorm 8.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

live edit is not stable at this time
it sometimes jump to wrong tab
try to restart webstrom to see if it works

Comment: Thanks. I think this more than the problem of webstorm.

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced same issue on Windows 7 (Not able to write anything on WebStorm_7.0.3).
I have uninstalled the existing AngularJS plugin and reinstall it and it works fine.